# Class system economy

Tags: politics, low-fantasy, cities

I want a class system in  an enclosed citadel with Roman times technology.

It  is based around the idea that the farmer class work the land to bring food to the entire country.

All farm lands are property of the Queen.

The citadel pays off the farmers with free services like Academy training, scholarship, free medications, teachers and more importantly shelter for the entire family.

The city is impenetrable with beehive-like hexagonal perimeters where each side of the hexagon is a thick wall with guard towers.

Even the farm lands are restricted into different hexagons.

The city is also built centered on a really high hill making the hexagons in the center of the city the hardest to attack.

The city is still vulnerable to sieges but has enough resources to destroy any invader.

Also the citizens are not humans but centaurs with an incredible power when compared to humans.

And when the population overgrows the city expands by building new hexagons where each exagon can hold enough space for 450 families, with this system every new hexagon requires less walls to be built depending on the direction, a new hexagon centered to the north side of two older hexagon only requires 4 walls to be built instead of 6.

My question is: as for now the citadel is focused on a strict class system based on devotion, to make it work do I have to isolate completely the citadel and not allowing any external trading?

Comment: This question is good, but I suggest splitting it in two: one about the need for a monetary system, the other about isolation.

Comment: Wait, they're like... Egyptians in cleopatra's time? (https://youtu.be/DiG0LomEptE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Similar Cultures

There are a lot of parallels between this and [Cleopatra's Egypt](https://youtu.be/DiG0LomEptE) and the [Inca](https://youtu.be/y2JiCR3djFI). I will be using these cultures to inform my answer.

Both of these cultures had a strong, central government and share features you described: direct control of land by the monarch, highly organized urban planning, and many government-run services.

## Trade?

While parts of these real-world empires were very isolated, they definitely *did trade* with other cultures. In fact, Cleopatra's Egypt was an agricultural powerhouse, often exporting grain to other regions.

## Money?

Money can still be a thing. Even money not backed by some real-world good can still be used, too. This being said, the centaur-government may find it more easy to avoid straight monetary payments for the services they provide.

Our real-world examples did a lot of in-kind trades or payments to make things easier. For your centaurs, this could be more of a "we gave X units of weight in seeds, you need to give us X+Y units of weight in seeds" or "The Queen gave you the land, you need to pay taxes in coin or goods come harvest-time."